# Docker and Java - FontConfiguration issue

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, aspose, aspose.words

We've got a Java application that generates word documents using a 3rd party (Asposee but I don't think it matters here). The app is built from a simple Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:10-jdk-slim
COPY target/*.jar /opt/
CMD $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /opt/*.jar
```

When we build the application locally (`mvn package` then `docker build`) and run the application inside `k8s` it works well.

However, when we build the image in our CI/CD pipeline with Jenkins we get a runtime exception when running through a specific process which apparently requires additional fonts:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1288)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:765)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:440)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:385)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
```

In that case the project is buit in Jenkins, compiled by the docker image `maven:3.5.4-jdk-10-slim`.

I've checked both jar files (locally and from jenkins) and the class files are the same (as expected).

In both cases it's the same base image so I don't understand what could be the difference. Is something different in Docker when building locally vs inside another Docker container?

**EDIT**

We've looked into both docker images and found the following difference.

Since locally built image `ls -l /usr/lib` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May  3  2017 X11
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Apr 26 00:00 apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 26 08:31 binfmt.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 cgmanager
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 dbus-1.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:51 dconf
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:51 debug
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 20 10:08 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 environment.d
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 25 04:56 gcc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:51 glib-networking
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 26 00:00 init
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:51 jvm
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 kernel
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    20 Mar  4 09:49 libnih-dbus.so.1 -> libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 34824 Mar  4 09:49 libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    15 Mar  4 09:49 libnih.so.1 -> libnih.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 92184 Mar  4 09:49 libnih.so.1.0.0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar 29 19:47 locale
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 lsb
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Jul 21  2017 mime
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 modprobe.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 26 08:31 modules-load.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   198 Jan 13 23:36 os-release
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:51 ssl
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 sysusers.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul 21  2017 tar
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Feb 11 20:06 terminfo
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Jun  6 01:50 tmpfiles.d
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Apr 26 00:00 udev
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 16384 Jun  6 01:51 x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But inside Jenkins built image `ls -l /usr/lib` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jun 25 00:00 apt
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul  3 01:00 debug
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 20 10:08 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 17 03:36 gcc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 25 00:00 init
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 Jul  3 01:00 jvm
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 Jul 12 11:00 locale
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul  3 01:00 lsb
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 May 16 07:47 mime
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  198 Jan 13 23:36 os-release
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul  3 01:00 ssl
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 20 10:08 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 16 07:47 tar
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 May 21 08:54 terminfo
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 25 00:00 tmpfiles.d
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 25 00:00 udev
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  3  2017 X11
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 Jul  3 01:00 x86_64-linux-gnu
```

This is really puzzling as I thought Docker would always produce the same image from identical Dockerfiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we found the problem.

When running on Jenkins we use the `docker:dind` (Docker inside docker) Docker image to provide the `docker` command in the build. This image is based on `Alpine` linux. When running `docker info` we get the following:

On Mac:

```
Kernel Version: 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Mac
```

On Jenkins:

```
Kernel Version: 4.4.115-k8s
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.7 (containerized)
```

`Alpine` linux must be missing those fonts. We fixed the problem by manually installing them in the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes apt-utils \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes software-properties-common \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes dbus \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes cgmanager \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes glib-networking \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes libnih-dbus-dev \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes dconf-cli \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes fontconfig
```

Not sure this is the minimum required libraries but those did the trick :D

Comment: Thanks for a well-explained answer :-) even though this wasn't the solution to my version of the problem.

Answer (score 15):

With openjdk:8u111-jdk-alpine, installing dejavu fix the problem:

For example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8u111-jdk-alpine
# Needed to fix 'Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag'
ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8

# JRE fails to load fonts if there are no standard fonts in the image; DejaVu is a good choice,
# see https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/73#issuecomment-207816707
RUN apk add --update ttf-dejavu && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

VOLUME /tmp
COPY /target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx100m","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: I tested with openjdk:8u111-jdk-alpine.

Comment: Works for me as well with openjdk:16-alpine

Comment: Worked for me using `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` and without the `ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8` declaration

Answer (score 7):

Just add the following in your Dockerfile

```
RUN apk add --no-cache fontconfig ttf-dejavu
```

Answer (score 5):

Installing `libfontconfig1` solved the problem for me ([source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/issues/75#issue-372523811)):

```
RUN apt-get install -y libfontconfig1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 2):

If you trying to do in Java/Spring boot , adding following in `Dockerfile` worked for me in java 11.

```
# Font packages to be added for java 11
RUN apk update \
 && apk add fontconfig \
 && apk add ttf-dejavu
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so && \
    ln -s /lib/libuuid.so.1 /usr/lib/libuuid.so.1 && \
    ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /usr/lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem NullPointerException with fonts occurs when you use openjdk docker image in **alpine** version for example :

adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine.

**You need change image to full version: adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9**

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on local with Docker Desktop and using docker file to create the image.
Please make changes in Dockerfile from FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine to FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue while running below command and restart app server resolved this issue.
Yup install fontconfig