# JMeterPluginsCMD.sh not running in Docker container

Tags: docker, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have JMeter 5.4 added to a Docker container, based on Alpine 3.12.0. I've added a few plugins, including the ones I have identified for JMeterPluginsCMD.sh. These are;

- jpgc-cmd-2.2
- jpgc-synthesis-2.2
- jpgc-filterresults-2.2

I am running an aggregate report based on a results JTL file.

```
/opt/jmeter/bin/JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv /test/aggregate.csv --input-jtl /test/results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

But I get a Java error (added below for clarity). The equivalent command on my local Windows PC (with the same plugins) works fine;

```
c:\jmeter-5.4.1\bin\JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv c:\temp\ar.csv --input-jtl c:\temp\results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

I can't see what's different, apart from one running on Linux and one on Windows.

Here's the first part of the error, I can add more if it's needed.

```
ERROR: java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: /opt/jmeter/lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
```

Comment: Did you tried with latest JMeter version?

Comment: Good plan, unfortunately no success. I've just this minute gone to jmeter 5.4.3, as well as the 3.15 Alpine Linux and openjdk 11, and it's still erroring. I don't think it's a version issue, I think it's a 'missing file' issue.

Comment: See if solutions help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55791235/pentaho-poi-throws-invocationtargetexception

Answer (score 0):

user7294900, I've no idea how you found that solution but it worked! I traced through the query to find the following;

```
run apk add --no-cache fontconfig ttf-dejavu
```

I added that to my dockerfile, and now the pluginsCMD works. Thank you so much, that was truly astounding.