# OpenJDK11 java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java

> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.font.CompositeFont cannot be cast to class sun.font.PhysicalFont (sun.font.CompositeFont and sun.font.PhysicalFont are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')
> java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1086)
> java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:965)
> java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFonts(SunFontManager.java:831)
> java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.loadFonts(SunFontManager.java:3182)
> java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.loadFonts(X11FontManager.java:438)
> java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.getAllInstalledFonts(SunFontManager.java:3543)
> java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:209)
> java.desktop/sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:72)
> ```

I have openjdk11 in my Centos server. I have seen this issue fixed by installing fontconfig package in os. Is there a way that i can fix this issue without installing any package?

I tried to copy some the *fontconfig.properties* files in my *$JAVA_HOME/lib/* folder

Comment: have you tried the answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61082904/1725871 `fc-cache -rv *pathoffonts*` or https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8221741

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.